# How to start-stop perl daemon from php

Tags: php, perl, daemon

I need to control (start\stop\restart) a perl daemon from a web application (php).
Daemon starts (and run) correctly when I use my init script (/etc/init.d/foodaemon start (works fine) ) from command line, but doesn't works (daemon is down but pid file is created, as if the daemon died after its creation) when I try to launch from application. 
In my /etc/sudoers, I added

```
apache  ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/foodaemon
```

In my php script,

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/init.d/foodaemon start";                             
exec($cmd,$out,$ret);
```

I have all permissions. The perl script is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Daemon;
Proc::Daemon::Init;

my $continue = 1;
$SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = 0 };

close STDIN;
open STDERR,">>/tmp/mylog";
print "My pid: $$\n";
close STDOUT;

while ($continue) {

        # ... what I need        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED... There was an error in my init.d script, or rather

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        if [ -z "$(pgrep $DAEMON)" ]
        then

            # DAEMON is not running                         
            printf "%-50s" "Starting $NAME..."

            cd $DAEMON_PATH
            PID=`$DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`

            #echo "Saving PID" $PID " to " $PIDFILE
            if [ -z $PID ]; then
                printf "%s\n" "Fail"
```

I did not have permission to do

```
cd $DAEMON_PATH
```

so, I update as follow

```
 #cd $DAEMON_PATH
 PID=`$DAEMON_PATH/$DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
```

and It works...Sorry...

Comment: Nice job. Why don't you hit the green checkmark on your answer so this one doesn't show up in the unanswered questions area.